# Remove leading zeros using HiveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a string value in which i might have leading zero's, so i want to remove all leading zeros.

**For example:**

```
accNumber = "000340" ---> "340"
```

Any UDF is available in Hive? can we use `regexp_extract` for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

```
SELECT some_string,
   REGEXP_REPLACE(some_string, "^0+", '') stripped_string
FROM db.tbl
```

(fixed simple typo with comma)

Comment: didn't know it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use,

```
SELECT cast(cast("000340" as INT) as STRING) col_without_leading_zeroes 
  FROM db.table;
```

**output** : 340 (Datatype will be string)

Hope this is helpful.