# How to remove leading zero's from string column in Hive/Impala

Tags: hive

If amount is "$0012304" then I want result like "$12304" and
if amount is "$0000000" then "$0"

When I use `regexp_replace(amount,'^?0', '')`, it is replacing all the zeros in the column and giving a result of $1234 instead of $12304.

I want to keep "$" in front of amount after removing all leading zeroes.

Comment: Welcome! to SO, Please be advised to search your question before posting it here if you follow the rules it will save everyone's time                                                         Here is the link to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146780/remove-leading-zeros-using-hiveql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove leading zeros using HiveQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146780/remove-leading-zeros-using-hiveql)

Comment: I want to keep "$" symbol in front of amount after removing all leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove dollar sign if exists, convert to double (it will remove leading zeroes), concatenate with dollar sign:

```
select concat('$',cast(regexp_replace('$000001','^\\$','') as double))
```

Result:

```
$1.0
```

Use `bigint` or `int` instead of `double` if the figures are integers only

This method will work if dollar sign is absent and with all zeroes also.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the linked question (possible duplicate) you could alter the selection to get your desired effect.  Here we match the '$' at the beginning of the string, followed by any amount of 0's, remove it, and add it back.

```
SELECT some_string,
   REGEXP_REPLACE(some_string, "^\\$0+", '$') stripped_string
FROM db.tbl
```

*edited to add an extra slash per feedback.

Comment: thanks a lot! but it worked after adding one more '\' into "^\\$0+"

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: thanks! but still challenge is when amount is "$000000" then would want it like "$0", if i use above method then it is only showing "$" in column instead of "$0"

Comment: `IF(stripped_string='$', '$0', stripped_string)`

This is beyond my understanding at this point though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
select regexp_replace(substring('$0012304',2),'^0+?','$') from hive_table;
```

First substring and then replace it with $.